# Swift Displaying Parse Image in TableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am attempting to display the users image that is saved to parse property "image". I have been able to display my username with no issue, but I can't seem to be able to get my image to appear. Should I be casting this information as UIImage? Am I correctly calling where the file is stored?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class SearchUsersRegistrationViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {    

    var userArray : NSMutableArray = []    

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        loadParseData()

        var user = PFUser.currentUser()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func loadParseData() {

        var query : PFQuery = PFUser.query()

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            if error == nil {                    
                if let objects = objects {

                    println("\(objects.count) users are listed")    
                    for object in objects {                            
                        self.userArray.addObject(object)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } else {
                println("There is an error")
            }
        }
    }



    let textCellIdentifier = "Cell"

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.userArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchUsersRegistrationTableViewCell

        let row = indexPath.row            
        var individualUser = userArray[row] as! PFUser
        var username = individualUser.username as String

        var profilePicture = individualUser["image"] as? UIImage            
        cell.userImage.image = profilePicture            
        cell.usernameLabel.text = username

        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func finishAddingUsers(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("finishAddingUsers", sender: self)            
    }       
}
```

Comment: I maybe wrong, but I think it downloads as a PFFile?

Comment: in your parse database, the image column has what type? It probably is a PFFile, but could also be referenced as a URL (probably better), that you can then download the image from.

Comment: Yes I believe PFFile, It has the data type of Bytes when I look in the database.

Comment: I think you have to d/l the image from the PFFile. Off the top of my head, it's something like getDataInBackground

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The photos are saved in a PFFile and not as a UIImage..

What makes your code the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchUsersRegistrationTableViewCell

        let row = indexPath.row            
        var individualUser = userArray[row] as! PFUser
        var username = individualUser.username as String

        var pfimage = individualUser["image"] as! PFFile

        pfimage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (result, error) in
            cell.userImage.image = UIImage(data: result)
        })        
        cell.usernameLabel.text = username

        return cell
    }
```

See more [in the docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#files/iOS)

Comment: Hey @RaVeN thank you for the response. This makes a lot more sense to me than my other approaches, but the app crashes when I cast as `PFFile`. Here is my error message: `Could not cast value of type '_NSInlineData' (0x107dd1cf8) to 'PFFile' (0x106216e80).` Any thoughts as to why that happened?

Comment: @cphill Is your column on the parse database a "File" column?
If not, change so

Comment: Yes, @RaVeN, that was the issue I was running into. Thank you so much for your time responding to my question

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> fileprivate func getImage(withCell cell: UITableViewCell, withURL url: String) {
>
>     Alamofire.request(url).responseImage { (image) in
>
>         /* Assign parsed Image */
>         if let parsedImage = image.data {
>             DispatchQueue.main.async {
>
>                 /* Assign Image */
>                 cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: parsedImage)
>
>                 /* Update Cell Content */
>                 cell.setNeedsLayout()
>                 cell.layoutIfNeeded()
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```